# How can Spinner content depend on another Spinner's selected item?

Tags: java, android

I need the `spinner2` content to be dependent of the selected item in `spinner1`, in this code `spinner2` takes his content only from `case0 : R.array.subMenuTrans` regardless of what is selected in `spinner1`.

```
package com.example.game1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DialogMenu extends AppCompatActivity { 

    Spinner spinner1;
    Spinner spinner2;    **spinners**
    Spinner spinner3;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_menu);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.menu, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition() + " is selected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }

        });

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.submenu);
        int options = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        switch (options) {
            case 0://spinner2 takes only content of case0,should take all cases depenting on selection of spinner1....
                adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.subMenuTrans, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                break;
            case 1:
                adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.subMenuSights, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);**takes content**
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                break;
            case 2:
                adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.subMenuEdu, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                break;
            case 3:
                adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.subMenuHeal, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                break;
            case 4:
                adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.subMenuBus, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                break;
            case 5:
                adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.subMenuAthl, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                break;
            case 6:
                adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.subMenuPubServ, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        }
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() + " is selected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onItemSelected must trigger the spinner2 init

Answer (score 0):

You're setting spinner2's position in onCreate() to be whatever spinner1's position is (during onCreate()).

onCreate() only gets called once, so spinner2's position only gets set once in this case.

One solution would be to change spinner2's position from inside spinner1's onItemSelected() method.